# Events in jasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, scriptlet

In *FastReports*, you can create events that can change the report structure before or after generating the report by changing the structure of the information, receiving parameters, and even the query structure.

There is the option that I believe is the way it is using *Scriptlets*, but it is not acceptable to use any that work.

*How do I implement the classes that would do the treatments before and after starting the creation of my report:*

[image]

I'm calling my class like this:

[image]

The error I got:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to add jar to cp (via "Java  Build Path" dialog at Studio)

Comment: The jar with you custom class (*br.com.*). There are no events at *JasperReports* engine in the same concept as *FastReports*

Comment: to this import you mean? [image](https://imgur.com/a/U7uUN)